# Getting an Error:(22, 20) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: string error when adding the string command

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm getting this error Error:(22, 20) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: string when I add some code to my learnign program I made in Intellij It runs ok until I add the string command then I get the error above.I have installed jdk-11.0.3_windows-x64_bin with ideaIC-2019.1.3.exe but not sure if this is the correct SDK to use? Or if this is causin the issues?

```
var department:string?
department = null
department ="software Engineering"
println ("department ${department}")
```

Information:Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.3.40 (JRE 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Information:Module "Varibles" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes

> Information:03/07/2019 16:20 - Build completed with 1 error and 0
>   warnings in 2 s 534 ms
>   C:\Users\lanca\IdeaProjects\Varibles\src\DataTypes.kt
>       Error:Error:line (22)Kotlin: Unresolved reference: string

Comment: `String` not `string`

Comment: Thanks for this did the trick just after I fig another way! :-) I added thistypealias string = Any to the top of the code! I don't know why it made it work but it did but I will stick to the capitail as you have stated! thanks. How do i mark resolved?

Comment: @Dave post a description of what you've made as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @forpas this fixed the issue! 
[image]